# Selecting columns in a table where table name is selected from another table and concatenate them selecting only specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I have a table:

```
   TableName  rn
    Tab_1     1
    Tab_2     2
    Tab_3     3
```

Tab_1, Tab_2 and Tab_3 are tables stored in the database.

What i want is to read all these tables using a loop, select specific columns (say col1, col2, and col3) and concatenate them.

What i tried was:

'''

```
DECLARE 
@table NVARCHAR(128),
@sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @table = N'select tablename from #db2 where rn=1';

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @table;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

'''
This query does not exactly concatenate the tables one by one but i am first trying to select the tables dynamically first before i use them in a loop. This does not seem to be working, it returns 'incorrect syntax near 'select''.
#db2 is the temp table that has all the table names.

I have looked at various methods but am not able to figure one out to suit this specific problem.

How do i go about working this out?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually storing SQL select statement into @table by the Set Statement

```
SET @table = N'select tablename from #db2 where rn=1';
```

Due to which the final @sql has the statement like "SELECT * FROM select tablename from #db2 where rn=1"

While you need to set the value into @table by

```
Select @table = db.TableName From #db2 As db With (Nolock) Where db.rn = 1
```

Try this way, it will work. You need either use While Loop or Cursor for your requirments.